# How do i create a new item by copying an existing item in the Sharepoint 2010 list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

How do i create a new item by copying an existing item in the Sharepoint 2010 list, so that i can save the newly copied file with or without changes.. workflow and infopath and custom coding are not allowed...sharepoint designer is allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use SPD, then why not SharePoint Designer Workflow ??, in the Sharepoint Designer Workflow you can make use of "Copy List Item" under Actions to fullfil your requirement.

Reference links:

> 1. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/9ba8e378-2633-4546-89ac-e63809d7f53c
> 2. http://www.go4sharepoint.com/Forum/sharepoint-designer-workflow-copy-9661.aspx

For grasping idea follow the below code,

> 1. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnwpowell/archive/2009/01/02/sharepoint-designer-copy-list-item-workflow-activity-does-not-copy-all-fields.aspx

Comment: thanks for the reply...i know how to do with workflow...but i need without using workflow and it is the requirement...someone can help me in this using ECMA script

Comment: then try the below links,  

1. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/1d01a48f-c28b-467b-acd1-22e5fb266670

2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205658/copy-selected-list-items-to-an-other-list-with-ecma-script

3. http://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/254736

For comman idea, refer below links

1.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx

2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185011(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: So, how do you copy the item with changes?

Answer (score 0):

is there any reason why custom coding is not allowed? well if the reason is you dont have a permission in your farm but given that you are a site collection admin you can consider using [SPListItem Copy](http://splistkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SP%20List%20Item%20Copy). This is free of use and is currently in sandboxed solution then you can just upload directly in your solution gallery and just activate the features.

Comment: strictly visual studio is not allowed here..u can help me using ECMA script

Comment: this is already in a wsp format so you just need upload in the solution gallery. 1. Download the file. 2. Upload in your solution gallery. 3. Activate the feature. 4. enjoy the copy list item functionality :)

Comment: thanks for the better solution....We have so many application in one site collection....as per your suggestion, it will get activated for all other app in site collection...we dont need so for other app...that why tey suggest to do in script/ECMA

Comment: What if your development machine is not running Windows Server, making it so that custom coding is impossible seeing as how SharePoint doesn't run on standard Windows environments, and you don't want to set up a standalone server or a virtual machine just for SharePoint development because that's incredibly STUPID???